STM32 F4 I2C loopback test
I have a STM32 f429zi disco board and I want to test I2C protocol.
I use I2C1 as master and I2C2 as slave but it can't work.
Code will get stuck at "while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1,I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED ));".
It looks like the I2C2 (slave) is not able to generate an ACK?
I use the MCU internal pull-up resistor now.
Should I use a external pull-up resistor?
Here is my code
char receivedata;
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x3D

void I2C1_Init(){
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOB_InitStruct = {
                .GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7,
                .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF,
                .GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz,
                .GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD,
                .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP
            };

    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIOB_InitStruct);

    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C1_InitStruct={
            .I2C_Ack=I2C_Ack_Enable,
            .I2C_AcknowledgedAddress=I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit,
            .I2C_ClockSpeed=100000,
            .I2C_DutyCycle=I2C_DutyCycle_2,
            .I2C_Mode=I2C_Mode_I2C,
            .I2C_OwnAddress1=0x00,
    };

    I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C1_InitStruct);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

}

void I2C2_Init(){

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOF, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C2, ENABLE);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource0, GPIO_AF_I2C2);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_I2C2);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOF_InitStruct = {
                .GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1,
                .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF,
                .GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz,
                .GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD,
                .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP
            };

    GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIOF_InitStruct);

    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C2_InitStruct={
            .I2C_Ack=I2C_Ack_Enable,
            .I2C_AcknowledgedAddress=I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit,
            .I2C_ClockSpeed=100000,
            .I2C_DutyCycle=I2C_DutyCycle_2,
            .I2C_Mode=I2C_Mode_I2C,
            .I2C_OwnAddress1=SLAVE_ADDRESS,
    };

    I2C_Init(I2C2, &I2C2_InitStruct);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C2, ENABLE);

    I2C_ITConfig(I2C2, I2C_IT_EVT, ENABLE);

    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct={
            .NVIC_IRQChannel=I2C2_EV_IRQn,
            .NVIC_IRQChannelCmd=ENABLE ,
            .NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=1,
            .NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority=1,
    };
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);
    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1);
}

void I2C1_start(){
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_FLAG_BUSY));

    I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);

    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1,I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));


    I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, (SLAVE_ADDRESS)<<1, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);

    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1,I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED ));


}

void I2C1_sned(char data){
    I2C_SendData(I2C1, data);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));
}

void I2C2_EV_IRQHandler(){
    switch(I2C_GetLastEvent(I2C2)){

        case I2C_EVENT_SLAVE_RECEIVER_ADDRESS_MATCHED:
            break;
        case I2C_EVENT_SLAVE_BYTE_TRANSMITTED:
            receivedata=I2C_ReceiveData(I2C2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

int main(){
    I2C1_Init();
    I2C2_Init();
    while(1){
        I2C1_start();
        I2C1_sned(senddata);
        I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2C1,ENABLE);
    }
    return 0;
}



Your magic functions most likely do not work as you think

Can you tell me how to where is the error in my code?

No one can tell you as you use unkniown library. Mixing interrupts and polling is not a very good idea

yes, you need a pull-up resistor as the GPIO configuration is OD, which means the bus can only pull the line low. The pull-up resistor is needed to pull the line high.

What is I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT? You set the start bit, and then check for I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT event. Given the event name, I don't understand how the event with that name has anything to do with the start bit. And what exactly is that event anyway?
